# How install crfsuite on Mac OS Monterey M1

Tags: macos, apple-m1

brew install fails on M1 Mac with Monterey and Xcode installed for arm64 arch
tried various options to get it work, but didn't work those.
**Other details:**
cmake: 3.22.2
clang:
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
autoconf: 2.71
make: 3.81
arch: arm64

```
lingamoorthi.ankam@LingamorthysMBP ~ % brew install crfsuite
...
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../include -I. -I./include -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -DUSE_SSE -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Winline -std=c99 -c src/lookup3.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/libcqdb_la-lookup3.o
error: unknown FP unit 'sse'
error: unknown FP unit 'sse'
make[1]: *** [libcqdb_la-cqdb.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [libcqdb_la-lookup3.lo] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
lingamoorthi.ankam@LingamorthysMBP ~ %
```

also in the similar way liblbfgs(crfsuite dependency) also failed, but manually installing it succeeded.
All tools installed are uptodate.

```
lingamoorthi.ankam@LingamorthysMBP ~ % cmake --version
cmake version 3.22.2
...
lingamoorthi.ankam@LingamorthysMBP ~ % automake --version
automake (GNU automake) 1.16.5
...
lingamoorthi.ankam@LingamorthysMBP ~ % clang --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
lingamoorthi.ankam@LingamorthysMBP ~ % autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.71
...
lingamoorthi.ankam@LingamorthysMBP ~ % make --version
...
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Comment: have you tried  `$ arch -x86_64 brew install crfsuite`? AFAIK, "unknown FP unit 'sse'"  it can be run only via Rosetta. But most probably you dont' want to compile your project against x86

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to disable sse2

Here is a suggestion

```
brew install crfsuite
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 3 taps (homebrew/core, homebrew/cask and brewsci/science).

You have 6 outdated formulae installed.
You can upgrade them with brew upgrade
or list them with brew outdated.

==> Downloading https://github.com/downloads/chokkan/crfsuite/crfsuite-0.12.tar.
Already downloaded: /Users/foo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/3b692f540345f335f203e8aa30a52e7279cba5d08e285130f811a02b565d8c46--crfsuite-0.12.tar.gz
==> Installing crfsuite from brewsci/science
==> ./configure --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/crfsuite/0.12
==> make install
...
error: unknown FP unit 'sse'
error: unknown FP unit 'sse'
make[1]: *** [libcqdb_la-cqdb.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [libcqdb_la-lookup3.lo] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Untar the downloaded crfsuite package

```
tar xvfz /Users/foo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/3b692f540345f335f203e8aa30a52e7279cba5d08e285130f811a02b565d8c46--crfsuite-0.12.tar.gz
```

Configure with disabled sse2 and other flags then make and install

```
cd crfsuite-0.12
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --disable-shared  --with-pic --disable-sse2
make
make install
```

Run `./configure --help` to get details of parameters